# Django link multiple tables

Tags: python, django

I write blog with django. And i have model table Article and i want 'like' it.Should I create new table?(like this)

```
class LikeArticleUser(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = "likearticleuser"

user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
article_id = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

or maybe

```
class LikeArticleUser(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = "likearticleuser"

user = models.ForeignKey(User)
article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Use M2M field in the `Article` model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Or create the intermediate table by yourself (which is the second snippet in our question):

```
class LikeArticleUser(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

SQL representation for both options will be the same so which option you choose is a matter of taste.